# Curve Integral typeset problem

Tags: math-mode, equations

I would like typeset equation on the figure below:
[image: curve integral]

I've tried code:

```
\begin{equation}\label{fyz:eq_fey_curveint1}
  \Psi(2)-\Psi(1) = 
    \begin{array}{l}
      \displaystyle\int_{(1)}^{(2)}(\nabla\Psi)\cdot\,d{\vec{s}} \\
      \text{po}\,\Gamma
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

with result:

[image: curve integral result]

As you can see on the left hand side of the equation is not correctly centered on the character of the integral. I try use solution from similar [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139515/math-equation-typeset-problem), discussed at the stackexchange web, but I did not get a satisfactory result. I hope that this group of very experienced users advise me again.

Comment: Drop the array, the po stuff is a (strange) part of the lower bound. Try _{\substack{(1)\\po....}}. Untested

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\po}{po}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production
\[
\Psi(2)-\Psi(1) = \int_{\substack{(1)\\\po\Gamma}}^{(2)}(\nabla\Psi)\cdot \textrm{d}\vec{s}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Compare with the scanned image on the question.

[image]

Is there any significant difference? I don't think so.

Comment: Now the limits `(1)` and `(2)` are not places similarly relativt to the integral; the `(1)` is placed too high. Also, the differential operator should be typeset using, e.g., `\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` and the `\dif`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: It is exactly similar to the requested answer, see the scanned image on the question.

Comment: in the original scan, the `\psi`s look like lowercase.  it's definitely an uppercase `\Gamma`, but i'm not anywhere i can check how to make it italic.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes it is one of the insignificant differences.

Comment: @Marienplatz - How do you know that use of `\Psi` instead of `\psi` constitutes an insignificant difference?

Comment: @Mico: Because `\psi` or `\Psi` is not the part on which I mainly focused.

Comment: @Marienplatz - And what you focus on is what's significant -- and everything else isn't? :-)

Comment: @Mico: Because when I read the question, it seemed to me the question is about the integral sign which is not properly aligned. So I started focusing on that part.

Comment: @barbara beeton: Perhaps a Cyrillic _Г_ can be used instead?

Comment: @g.kov -- i think that wouldn't be very good practice.  think about meaning, not just appearance.  try `\varGamma`.  (i'm hesitant because i'm many thousand miles from my reference library, having just attended tug 2013 in tokyo.)

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Psi(2)-\Psi(1)={\displaystyle
\int_{\underset{\operatorname{{po}\,
\Gamma}}{(1)}}^{(2)}}
(\nabla\Psi)\cdot \mathrm{d}{\vec{s}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: This looks like a "proper" solution. The only thing is the differential operator; see comment to [Marienplatz' answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140759/15874).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, I see, thanks. Now "d" is uprigth.

Answer (score 7):

TeX Primitives are still cool:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{fyz:eq_fey_curveint1}
    \Psi(2)-\Psi(1) = 
      \displaystyle\int_{(1)\atop\text{po}\,\Gamma}^{(2)}(\nabla\Psi)\cdot\,\mathrm{d}\vec{s}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:** There is one thing that I would adjust. Instead of the `\text{po}\,\Gamma`, I would rather do

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\po}{po}
```

and replace it by `\po\Gamma`.

**Edit 2:** For size correction of the subscript you have to do `_{\scriptstyle (1)\atop\scriptstyle\po\Gamma}`.

[image]

Comment: As always, \text is not the proper command to use here. Po is most likely an operator so declare it as such or use say \operatorname. Then we don't risk that user going through the archives end up thinking that \text is a good solution in cases like this

Comment: @daleif, this is what came to me in my mind just now :-) See my edit.

Comment: @daleif: There still is a chance that on the contrary,
this `po` is not an operator, but just a Polish word (=English `in`).

Comment: @g.kov, makes sense. Though never seen that syntax before

Answer (score 6):

With a new definition of `subarray` taking also an optional argument `[t]` (for “top alignment”), the result seems better. The following document shows two variants: one with left alignment in the `subarray`, the other one with center alignment (and `\hidewidth` so that the bottom line is “invisible” as far as the width of the `subarray` is concerned).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} % for the bold italic s

\DeclareMathOperator{\po}{po}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subarray}[2][c]{%
  \if#1t\vtop\else\vcenter\fi\bgroup
  \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
  \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
  \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
  \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
  \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\ifx c#2\hfil\fi
    $\m@th\scriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\psi(2)-\psi(1)=
\int_{\begin{subarray}[t]{l}
      (1)\\
      \po\Gamma
      \end{subarray}}
    ^{(2)}
  (\nabla\psi)\cdot\diff\bm{s}.
\]

\[
\psi(2)-\psi(1)=
\int_{\begin{subarray}[t]{c}
      (1)\\
      \hidewidth\po\Gamma\hidewidth
      \end{subarray}}
    ^{(2)}
  (\nabla\psi)\cdot\diff\bm{s}.
\]

\end{document}
```

It's not clear whether the psi in the text is lower or upper case; my impression is that it's lower case. The slanted or upright Gamma is probably a stylistic decision.

With the new form of `subarray` the optional argument can be `t` or `c` (which is the default). I don't think adding a `b` option is worthwhile.

[image]

Comment: There should be no dot between `\nabla` and `\psi`. It is not in the original and it does not make mathematical sense. Also the original scan contains a bold `s`. This could be gotten with `\bm{s}` if the `bm` package is loaded.

Comment: @Dan Oh, I overlooked it.